# Python 3.11 - IIS 10 - AttributeError: Module has no attribute 'wsgi'

Tags: python-3.x, django, web-applications, iis-10

I have a Python (3.11) web application using Django 4.2.5 deployed to a Windows 2019 Server running IIS 10.

I have deployed several Python + Django apps to IIS WebServers previously with no issues, however they were older versions (Windows 2016, python 3.8, django 3.2)

I don't expect that much has changed since then so when deploying this application I mimicked the configuration of IIS, however it continues to give me the same error.

- I have all of the Windows Features installed (IIS, CGI, .Net 3.5 and 4, etc)
- I have configured the Environment Variables in the FastCGI settings (IIS WebServer level), and the Application Settings (on the site level)
- I have configured the Handler Mappings

And yet no success. Hoping someone can help point me in the right direction.

**
My Application Folder Structure (in case it's important) **
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNexE.png)

**In settings.py**
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'main.root.wsgi.application'

**In wsgi.py**
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'root.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()

I'm sorry if I left out any information that's relevant. This is my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following methods to solve the problem:

- It may cause by the extra directory module"xxx", remove it and try
  again.
- Check your Project-Folder, you will find a __ init__.py file, remove
  it and try again.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read my question and post a reply. Which folder would you consider "Project-Folder" based on the screenshot of the directories I included?

Comment: You're right, the extra directory was the issue. Why is that? I tried configuring my settings to have main.root.settings or main.root.wsgi.application. Having one extra directory doesn't seem like something that would break the application as long as everything is configured properly.